# Como acceder a los elementos del nav_header

Tags: java, android-studio

He creado un navegation drawer Activity y quiero modificar los elementos a traves de los datos que extraigo de una api rest, pero no se como acceder a ellos desde la Activity principal

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    tvUsuario=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvUsuarioHeader);
    tvUsuario.setText(email);
```

El archivo XML del layout

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivHeader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvUsuarioHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvEmailHeader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Hola, podrias agregar el layout con los elementos a los que deseas modificar?

Comment: El archivo XML del layout??

Comment: ¿Que elementos deseas acceder?

Comment: A un imagenView y dos textview y poner los datos de usuario, cuando intento acceder cómo puse en el código me salta el error de que no hace referencia a ningún objeto el id

Comment: si el xml del layout donde tenes esos imageView y TextView

Comment: Lo subí arriba @ErickSilva